# Pymongo finding all Mongo records where value is between two mongo index values

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I have a list of values

```
myValues = [5,6,7,8,9]
```

I have record as follows

```
record1 = {"_id" : someID, "index" : datetime, "StartValue" : 1, "EndValue" : 8}
record2 = {"_id" : someID, "index" : datetime, "StartValue" : 9, "EndValue" : 16}
record3 = {"_id" : someID, "index" : datetime, "StartValue" : 17, "EndValue" : 24}
...
```

Now, I would like to perform a search query using `find()` such that one or more records are included in the returned cursor, where the returned elements have a StartValue and EndValue that together include all of the values in list `myValues`. In the above case, `record1` and `record2` would be returned. Values `[5,6,7,8]` would correspond to `record1` since it falls between and including the `StartValue` and `EndValue`. `record2` is returned because element `[9]` of `myValues` is within `record2`'s `StartValue` and `EndValue`.

I have tried the following:

```
myData = myMongoCollection.find({"index" : {"$gt" : current_time - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)}, "$and" : {{"StartValue" : {"$gte" : {"$or" : myValues}}}, {"EndValue" : { "$lte" : {"$or" : myValues}}}} } )
```

**Edit** I have tried using `$gte` and `$lte` to try to capture array values that may not match the `StartValue` and `EndValue`. For this reason, the `$in` operator would not work. For example, if `myValues=[5,6,7]`, then `record1` will **not** be returned when using `$in`. However, I would like to have `record1` returned in that case as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get minimum and maximum numbers from `myValues` array, and check `$gte` and `$lte` condition with `$or` operator for both the properties,

```
myValues = [5,6,7,8,9]
minValue = min(myValues)
maxValue = max(myValues)

myData = myMongoCollection.find({
  "index": {
    "$gt": current_time - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
  }, 
  "$or": [
    {
      "StartValue": { "$lte": minValue },
      "EndValue": { "$gte": minValue }
    },
    {
      "StartValue": { "$lte": maxValue },
      "EndValue": { "$gte": maxValue }
    }
  ]
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XFc8N570JZf)